# .dylib linked in Debug, not found for Release for iPhone in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I have included the libxml2.2.dylib library into my iPhone XCode project to create some Xml and XPath parsing utilities.  When I compile and run in Debug mode for both the Simulator and Device I have no problems, however, When I switch to Release mode I get...

"error: libxml/tree.h: No such File or directory"  as well as other similar errors for the following .h files.

```
#import <libxml/tree.h>
#import <libxml/parser.h>
#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
#import <libxml/xpath.h>
#import <libxml/xpathInternals.h>
```

What do I need to do to ensure the libary is included and linked to the Release build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An error on the .h is a compile-time error with your Header Search Paths, not a .dylib or a linker error.

You have to ensure that `${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2` is in your Header Search Paths in your Release configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that was it!

Answer (score 7):

i was going around in circles this morning with this same problem with xcode 4.

again as described exactly above, it builds with fine with
Schema > 
    Build Configuration 
    --> **Debug**
 but fails when switching it to **Release**

tried numerous cleans and 
adding ${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2 or
$/usr/include/libxml2 
and triple checking Header Search Paths / checking the recursive check box all to no avail. 
Was about to start a new project when ....

I managed to resolve it by adding
${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2 to the **User Header Search Paths**

Answer (score 0):

do make sure that libxml is included in your project , that was the one that caused the problem for me.

add libxml2.2.7.3.dylib to linked libraries